# Yesod 1.4 Authentification Logout "Permission denied"

Tags: yesod

I'm trying out the authentication and authorization example from yesodweb.
The login works fine now with BrowserId and Google but when I want to logout I get a:

> Permission denied
>
> A valid CSRF token wasn't present in HTTP headers or POST parameters. >Check the Yesod.Core.Handler docs of the yesod-core package for details >on CSRF protection.

This is the form send from the auth subsite after clicking on the logout link: http://lpaste.net/150405.
It's obvious that the token is not in the form, but the token is in the cookie my browser is sending in the POST with the form: http://lpaste.net/150406.

What I'm doing wrong here? I don't want to be logged in forever :)